# Android Custom ViewGroup not rendering correctly

Tags: java, android, listview, viewgroup

I have a `ViewGroup` that has the following xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_viewLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ticketBuy_icon"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ticketBuy_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Later, I put these Views into a ListView. And, well, don't really get the desired result.

What I want it to be is a small rectangular view with an image to the left, a title to the top right and the date to the bottom left. I am not posting the ListView xml because it does not have anything that would be of use (just a width and height set to match_parent) However, all I get is this (This ListView has about 8 elements):

[image]

Comment: Please show code used to create the ArrayList<yourcustomcalss> and your custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @RickFalck I did not use a custom adapter, because I did not see what difference it would make, since I do not want any special actions. Could you help with an answer?

Comment: @RickFalck Ahh... damn, I should've done more research. I am going to add the custom array adapter and then post my results. Sorry, pretty new to android as you see

Answer (score 0):

I think you just messed up with the layout.

Try this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_viewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ticketBuy_icon"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketBuy_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ticketBuy_name"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, still the same thing